# Terraform: If subnetwork does not exist, set interface to null

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am creating a custom module that creates a multi-nic VM in GCP.  At deployment, there may be occasions when the VM does not need to use multiple interfaces.

Is it possible to set the network_interface to a null value if the subnetwork does not exist?  I want to avoid having to create multiple modules for each interface count if possible.

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "vm" {
  name                      = "${var.vm_name}"
  machine_type              = "${var.machine_type}"
  zone                      = "${var.zone}"
  min_cpu_platform          = "${var.cpu_platform}"

  network_interface {
    subnetwork    = "${google_compute_subnetwork.subnetwork1.name}"
  }
  network_interface {
    subnetwork    = "${google_compute_subnetwork.subnetwork2.name}"
  }

  network_interface {

// PSEUDO CODE
    subnetwork   = if (subnetwork3 == true) {
                      "${google_compute_subnetwork.subnetwork3.name}"
                   else 
                      "do nothing or set null"
  }
}
```

Comment: Setting arguments to `null` becomes available in 0.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you combine `locals` with a `count`?

Example

```
locals {
  interface_num = "${var.is_subnetwork_3 ? 0 : 3}"
}

resource "google_whatever" "name" {
  count = "${local.interface_num}"
  // config
}
```